# Get average time between times in SQL

Tags: sql, mysql

I'm really clueless as how to do this.

Say my table looks like so:

```
MESSAGES
- id
- date_posted
- content
```

How do I get the average time between postings? (date_posted)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT  AVG(period)
FROM    (
        SELECT  TIME_TO_SEC(TIMEDIFF(@date_posted, date_posted)) AS period,
                @date_posted := date_posted
        FROM    (
                SELECT @date_posted := NULL
                ) vars,
                messages
        ORDER BY
                date_posted
        ) q
```

Comment: hey it works! but it gives a value like "16775640.3" what unit is that? how do i convert to days or hours?

Comment: @Obay: sorry, there was a little glitch, I updated the query. This will be in seconds.

Comment: Could you explain why this works? I think I understand, but I want to be sure about it.

Comment: @RobertK: The second expression sets the session variable to `date_posted`, the first expression compares the current `date_posted` with the session variable (set to the value from the previous record).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(s, M2.Date_Posted, M1.Date_Posted)) as AverageSeconds
   FROM Messages M1 INNER JOIN Messages M2 ON M1.Id = M2.Id+1
```

Sorry this is MS-SQL solution not mySQL - apologies only just realised that is what you were after. This may be of use to someone else.

In response to comment below - in SQL Server 2005 or 2008 - the following would be a better solution because it makes no assumption about sequential or in-fact integer Primary Keys as it uses Row_Number to generate a unique, sequential key:

```
SELECT AVG(DATEDIFF(s, M2.Date_Posted, M1.Date_Posted)) as AverageSeconds
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date_Posted ASC) as Id, Date_Posted FROM 
            Messages) M1
    INNER JOIN (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Date_Posted ASC) as Id, Date_Posted 
            FROM Messages) M2 ON M1.Id = M2.Id+1
```

Comment: The above code assumes that Ids are strictly sequential, which is not always the case. Moreover, who said that Ids were INTs and not GUIDs or VARCHARs, for example?