# Average time between records MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, datetime

I have a table that contains records of articles. Now I want to calculate the average time between the articles from a source, so I can automatically increase or decrease my crawler interval. Is that possible with a MySQL Query if I select records from one source between 2 dates?

Table layout:

```
id | title    | description    | create_date          | source_id  
-----------------------------------------------------------------
1  | Title 1  | A description  | 2013-04-09 21:38:00  | 5
2  | Title 2  | A description  | 2013-04-09 22:16:00  | 5
3  | Title 3  | A description  | 2013-04-09 23:54:00  | 5
```

The outcome should be:

```
diff between 1 and 3 = 136 min
-----------------------------
Average is 45,33 minutes (crawler interval: 2720 seconds)
```

I could also do this in PHP if that is better!

Comment: try this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237159/get-average-time-between-times-in-sql
or this:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237159/get-average-time-between-times-in-sql


cheers:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yep.

```sql
SELECT
  UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MAX(create_time)) - UNIX_TIMESTAMP(MIN(create_time)) / COUNT(*) AS 'avg'
FROM table
WHERE source_id = 5
  AND create_time BETWEEN '2013-04-01 00:00:00' AND NOW()
```